# Mounting a NAS in the backend

Tags: backend, nas

Over the years I have been running an applescript program to connect to server when wanting to mount specific volumes on my MAC.

Once being logged onto an account the attached appelscript works without any problem.

Part of the activities I am using filemaker pro and now want be more efficient, I do now want to use Perform Script On Server (PSoS). However, since all of my data reside on a Network-Attached Storage (NAS) specifics volumes need to be mounted in the back-end.

I wanted to know if this would be possible to mount the required volumes in the back-end using the attached appelscript code. If possible, would someone tell me where to look for documentation?

```
--
-- AppleScript : MountFARAMIR
-- Version : 1.1 
--
-- Coder: Daniel Paquin
-- Date: January 2019
--
-- Input Variables (parameters): 
--     volumetobemounted
--     serveraddress
--
-- Output Variables
--

tell application "Finder"
    set volumetobemounted to "Data"
    set serveraddress to "smb://username:password@NN.N.N.NN/"
    set mounted_disks to list disks -- Get list of mounted disk


    if mounted_disks does not contain volumetobemounted then --Verify if volume Data has been mounted
        try
            mount volume serveraddress & volumetobemounted -- Mount volume at Server Address

        on error errMSG number errorNumber
            display dialog ("There was a problem mounting FARAMIR/DATA : " & errorNumber as text) & ", please notify your system administrator"
            return
        end try

    end if
end tell
```

In the meantime, I have been trying another solution by adding a auto_smb within the etc folder. Unfortunately I have not been able to get the auto_master and auto_smb to work.

the auto_master looks like this:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master            # Use directory service
/net                    -hosts          -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home                   auto_home       -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers        -fstab
/-                      -static
/-      auto_smb        -nosuid,noowners
#/-                     auto_afp        -nobrowse,nosuid
```

the auto_smb looks like this:

```
#
# 
#

/mount/Data  -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw ://username:password@NN.N.N.NN:/Data
/mount/Anonymous WebDav -fstype=smbfs,soft,noowners,nosuid,rw ://username:password@NN.N.N.NN:/Anonymous WebDav
```

The auto_master and the auto_smb file permission is  :
-rw-r--r--   root  wheel

I've restarted the auto_fs service with the command 'sudo sudo automount -cv'

The following is the result of restarting the auto_fs services.

```
automount: /net updated 
automount: /home updated 
automount: /Mount/Data updated 
automount: /Mount/Anonymous updated 
automount: no unmounts
```

- When looking at the /Mount folder I can see a /Data and an /Anonymous subfolder. Why is it that I see /Anonymous rather than /Anonymous WebDav?
- In the meantime when going the to /Volumes folder neither the /Data
  and /Anonymous WebDav are showing? Why's that? I am asking because when using the applescript above or the go to Connect to server the folder /Volumes than show a /Data subfolder.
- Is there a way to run a debug process when testing the auto_master
  and auto_smb file?
- Is there a log where I could see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script schedule in the FileMaker Server admin console to call an applescript at a set time. This could be your script to mount the NAS

https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fms/en/index.html#page/FMS_Help/schedule-run-system-script.html

Note that the script itself can only be in one location: the FMS scripts folder, if it is not there you wouldn't be able to select it when you set up the schedule.

Also be aware of permissions: both on the script file itself (owner and group has to be fmserver / fmsadmin ) and the script will be executed in the context of that fmserver user.  That user needs the proper rights to do what you want.